# Архивирование директорий

Tags: java, android, файлы, zip

Проблема заключается в том что в архиве у меня такой путь:

**/data/data/app.service.photoapp/files/name/33

Заменить/упростить надо на:

**name/33/**

или

**33/**

Код:

```
// folder.getPath().toString()="/data/data/app.service.photoapp/files/"
// folder.getName()="name"

Zip(folder.getPath()+"/"+folder.getName(),folder.getPath()+"/"+"zip.zip");
```

Метод `Zip()`

```
private void Zip(String source_dir, String zip_file) throws Exception
        {
            FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(zip_file);
            ZipOutputStream zout = new ZipOutputStream(fout);
            File fileSource = new File(source_dir);
            addDirectory(zout, fileSource);
            zout.close();

            Log.i(TAG,"Zip файл создан!");
        }
```

Метод `addDirectory()`

```
private void addDirectory(ZipOutputStream zout, File fileSource)
            throws Exception
    {
        File[] files = fileSource.listFiles();
        Log.i(TAG,"Добавление директории <" + fileSource.getName() +"> длина <"+files.length+">");
        for(int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            Log.i(TAG,"for");
            // Если file является директорией, то рекурсивно вызываем
            // метод addDirectory
            if(files[i].isDirectory()) {
                addDirectory(zout, files[i]);
                continue;
            }
            Log.i(TAG,"Добавление файла <" + files[i].getName() + ">");

            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(files[i]);

            zout.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(files[i].getPath()));

            byte[] buffer = new byte[4048];
            int length;
            while((length = fis.read(buffer)) > 0)
                zout.write(buffer, 0, length);
            // Закрываем ZipOutputStream и InputStream
            zout.closeEntry();
            fis.close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Если в папке `files` нет подпапок, только файлы, то в строке `zout.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(files[i].getPath()));` замените `getPath` на `getName`. Если подпапки есть, то вычислить длину префикса и обрезать путь методом `subString`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Спасибо **@woesss** подтолкнул меня на мысль и я сделал так:

```
private void addDirectory(ZipOutputStream zout, File fileSource)
            throws Exception
    {
        File[] files = fileSource.listFiles();
        Log.i(TAG,"Добавление директории <" + fileSource.getName() +"> длина <"+files.length+">");
        for(int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            Log.i(TAG,"for");
            // Если file является директорией, то рекурсивно вызываем
            // метод addDirectory
            if(files[i].isDirectory()) {
                addDirectory(zout, files[i]);
                continue;

            }
            Log.i(TAG,"Добавление файла <" + files[i].getName() + ">");

            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(files[i]);
            zout.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(files[i].getParentFile().getName()+"/"+files[i].getName()));


            byte[] buffer = new byte[4048];
            int length;
            while((length = fis.read(buffer)) > 0)
                zout.write(buffer, 0, length);
            // Закрываем ZipOutputStream и InputStream
            zout.closeEntry();
            fis.close();
        }
    }
```